# Using IPad SDK and XCODE IDE on Windows7

Tags: ipad

We have windows7 environment and expertise. We want to develop apps for Apple IPad using IPad SDK and XCODE IDE etc.

How can we use these tools on Windows environment?

Regards,
Chandan

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Virtual Machine, but it comes with headaches and hacks that need to be done to boot.  Just go buy a Mac Mini(cheap entry) and get to coding. XCode will **not** run on a windows machine natively.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of your app, one of the cross-platform development tools like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com) or [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-sdk/) might be appropriate. Xcode is a Mac-only app and will not run on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There is step by step tutorial how to setup it on virtual machine on most of windows machines.. http://ipodtoucher55.blogspot.de/2010/12/installing-ios-sdk-and-xcode-on-windows.html

hope it helped..